# How to binary a torch tensor but keep backpropagation?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

My problem is `How to binary a torch tensor but keep backpropagation from loss to it in a neural network`.

Specifically, Suppose in a neural network, I obtain a float tensor `a` through some functions, and its range is [0,1]. I want to binarize this tensor to a new tensor `b`, that is, if `a[i] > 0.5`, then `b[i]=1`, otherwise `b[i]=0` (`i` is the index of the tensor). Then I use `b` to obtain loss and use backpropagation to train the model.

I tried three methods to binarize `a`, but neither of them gave me satisfying results:

(1) change `a` directly

```
b=a * 1  # To make a copy of a
b[b>0.5] = 1.0
b[b<0.5] = 0.0
...  # Ingore some unnecessary procedures and we obtain loss.
```

I tried to calculate the gradients of `a` using `torch.autograd.grad(loss, a, retain_graph=True)`, and got `tensor[0, 0, ...]`. Note that `b.is_leaf=False`, it means `b` is a connected node of `a` in computation graph, and the backpropagation mechanism can calculate the gradients from loss to `a`, but I have no idea why the gradients are all 0, it is so weird.

(2) change `a.data` directly

```
b=a * 1  # To make a copy of a
b.data[b>0.5] = 1.0
b.data[b<0.5] = 0.0
...  # Ingore some unnecessary procedures and we obtain loss.
```

I tried to calculate the gradients of `a` using `torch.autograd.grad(loss, a, retain_graph=True)`, and got `tensor[nan, nan, ...]`. However, `b.is_leaf=False`, it means `b` is a connected node of `a` in computation graph, and the backpropagation mechanism can calculate the gradients from loss to `a`.

(3) use `torch.where`

```
b = torch.where(a>0.5, torch.ones_like(a), torch.zeros_like(a))
...  # Ingore some unnecessary procedures and we obtain loss.
```

I tried to calculate the gradients of `a` using `torch.autograd.grad(loss, a, retain_graph=True)`, and got `RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior.` This is because `b.is_leaf=True`, which means `b` is a new leaf node in the computation graph and it does not connect to `a`, thus the gradients can not be calculated.

**I want to binarize `a` but keep backpropagation from loss to `a`**, however, the above three methods can not solve my problem. Is there other methods can solve my problem? I think I need help since I am a beginner of pytorch and not very familiar with it.  I would appreciate it if you could give me some advices. Many thanks.

I put it in the details of my problem.

Comment: Please ignore the last sentence "I put it in the details of my problem." :)

Answer (score 0):

The function `f: x -> I(x>0.5)` is not differentiable on `x=0.5` and its derivative is null everywhere else. Therefore you have no information to backpropagate.

One alternative would be to use a softer version of `f` for example a sigmoid. In your case that would be `g: x -> sigmoid(x-0.5)`:

[image]

Also could use the hyperbolic tangent `h: x -> tanh(x-0.5)`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Frankly, I considered the sigmoid function before, that is, g: x -> sigmoid((x-0.5) * 100) (multiplying x-0.5 with 100 would make the output approach to 0 and 1). However,  through a simple experiment, I find the outputs are not satisfying since some elements of the tensor still can't be binarized. Though x-0.5 can be multiplied with larger number (e.g., 10^3, 10^4), I worry it will make the model training unstable. Based on your suggestions, now I will try it in a complete experiment.